# I'm trying to make a function that adds up only the odd numbers in my array but it isn't working

Tags: actionscript-3

In my computer course we need to make a program that does a bunch of things with arrays, for example, add all the even or all the odd numbers at the click of a button but I'm starting with the odd number total and it isn't working. Sorry about the french comments. Here's the function http://pastebin.com/4gCCE72y Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get odd and even numbers from an array, you have just to use a for loop with your array and verify every time if your number is odd to add it to odd numbers array, otherwise, add it to even numbers array, and calculating the sum of each array in the same time :

```
var array:Array = [5,44,30,96,9,95,51,14,38,64,57,86,64,48,31,11,89,51,24,4];

var odds:Array = [],
    evens:Array = [],
    odds_sum:int = 0,
    evens_sum:int = 0
;

for(var i:int = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] % 2 == 1){
        odds.push(array[i]);
        odds_sum += array[i];
    } else {
        evens.push(array[i]);
        evens_sum += array[i];
    }
}

trace(odds);        // gives : 5,9,95,51,57,31,11,89,51
trace(odds_sum);    // gives : 399

trace(evens);       // gives : 44,30,96,14,38,64,86,64,48,24,4
trace(evens_sum);   // gives : 512
```

**Note :** you can put your code into the body of your question, you are not forced to use pastebin.com.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks. And I just personally prefer using pastebin.